# Convergence of series defined by sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Okay, so I'm ever so slightly stuck on a question that sounds as follows

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence such that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2 \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^2$$  where $N\geq 1$ is a natural numbers. Use then this result to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$$ converges.

Okay, so at first when I was looking at the sums in part one of the question it immediately looked similar to the cauchy-schwarz special case where we let $b_i$=1 such that 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^2 \leq N\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2$$

But it seems like a "this ain't it chief" moment.

As for the last part of the tasken, given the result in the question preceeding it, I was thinking using the comparison tests could be doable, but I'm not really sure where to start.

If someone could push me in the right direction that would be great!

Also I tagged this question as real-analysis because I wasn't sure whether this kind of question would be dipping its toe into that world, so I'm sorry if this is the wrong tag.

Answer (score 1):

We are using that for any $n$

$$a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2 \le (a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)=\\=(a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2)+(2a_1a_2+2a_1a_3+\ldots+2a_{n-1}a_n) $$

then $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2 $ coverges since it is increasing and bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction: $N=1$ is trivial. Let the inequality hold for $N$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}a_n\right)^2
&= \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n + a_N\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\right)^2 + 2a_N\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n + a_N^2\\
&\ge\,\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n^2 + 2a_N\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n + a_N^2\,\ge\,\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n^2 + a_N^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{N+1}a_n^2.
\end{align*}

To show that $\sum_na_n^2$ converges, use the proved inequality and the very definition of limits of series (and the continuity of $x\mapsto x^2$).